# Spark Scala Dataframe: How to handle money datatype in PostgreSQL table?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need save a dataframe into PostgreSQL table, which has some fields with Money Datatype.

I tried to cast the data to DoubleType before storing, which does not seem to be working. The reported error is as following.

```
column "cost" is of type money but expression is of type double precision
```

Which datatype should I cast to store into PostgreSQL table with money datatype? Thanks!

Comment: try decimal type?

Comment: Check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-money.html

Comment: thanks. I tried to cast to DecimalType. Are there some special casting method I need to use to cast to DecimalType? I used the same approach to cast,  "withColumn("cost", inputdf("cost").cast(DecimalType)).". It generated the error as  error: overloaded method value cast with alternatives:
[ERROR]   (to: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
[ERROR]   (to: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType)org.apache.spark.sql.Column. But  I never found this error for DoubleType.

Answer (score 1):

```
// v 1
val df1 = sourceDF.withColumn("cost", 'cost.cast("decimal(25,10)"))

// v 2
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType
val df2 = sourceDF.withColumn("cost", 'cost.cast(new DecimalType(25, 10)))
```

Comment: Thanks. The key point is that we need provide precision and scale.  I finally used the below statement. It is working well. ```val df = inputDF.withColumn("cost", col("cost").cast(DecimalType(20,2)))```